# Are the pions really all that light?

Tags: mass, standard-model, symmetry-breaking, pions, sigma-models

I'm studying the sigma model where the pions are identified as the (pseudo) Nambu-Goldstone bosons of chiral symmetry breaking ("pseudo" from mild isospin symmetry violation). This argument usually concludes with "and that's why the pions are so light". I don't find this convincing when I consider the meson mass spectrum, for instance at

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/particles/meson.html

The pions are around 140 MeV which is definitely smaller than the next light-quark rho mesons in the 700's, but is this really so significant? According to Langacker (*The Standard Model and Beyond*, 2010), isospin is broken in QCD by only a few percent; this leads me to wonder why the pion is as *heavy* as it is!

Comment: Have you actually calculated what mass the "few percent" give when you plug all values into the formula for the mass? Our feelings about how "light" or "heavy" the poins are are pretty irrelevant, relevant is what the model actually predicts.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Wow, I'd love to see that fleshed out into an answer.

Comment: When you work out a concrete model for chiral symmetry breaking (or use effective field theory: the chiral perturbation theory), you will see that the pion mass is proportional to the *square root* of the quark mass. Hence even relatively light quarks can give you a rather heavy pion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a factor of six, $\approx m_\rho/m_\pi$ ***is*** a big deal, for mesons consisting of the same quarks! In the same vein, QCD scales are normally around a quarter of a GeV, so pions, more than all pseudoscalar mesons, appear to defy it.

The reason is they are the pseudogoldstone bosons of spontaneously/dynamically broken [chiral symmetry breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_symmetry_breaking#Footnotes), and the [Dashen formula](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/675155/fundamental-scales-in-qcd/675187#675187) (often coded as the Gell-Mann―Oakes―Renner formula) dictates that $m_\pi \sim \sqrt{m_q}$ 50MeV, where $m_q$ is the relevant [light quark](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/637138/which-quarks-can-form-vacuum-condensates/637302#637302) mass in MeV.

In practice,
$$
m_d\sim 4.7 MeV, \qquad m_u\sim 2.2MeV, \leadsto \\
m_d/m_u\sim 2.2, \qquad {m_d-m_u\over \Lambda _{QCD}}\sim 1.3 \%, 
$$
as Langacker  reminds you. So, isospin is only broken explicitly, *not* spontaneously, and is a *very good* symmetry,
$m_{\pi^+}- m_{\pi^0}\sim 4.6$MeV. However,  isospin is a total aside in this question, behaving very differently than the axial symmetries which are SSBroken! (You might wonder how a quark twice the mass of the other can lead to this symmetry, but the point is, as you see, that they are *both* much-much smaller than the hadronization scales of QCD. *That's* the meaning of isospin.)

By stark contrast, the flavored chiral symmetries spontaneously broken, the axials, are  responsible for protecting the masses of the pions from being dragged up to strong interaction scales closer to a GeV.