# Which quarks can form vacuum condensates?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, condensation

I faintly remember the rule of thumb that only the up, down and strange quarks can form condensates because their mass is below the QCD scale $\Lambda_\text{QCD}$. But why is that? Where‘s the connection between condensates and the QCD scale?

Comment: Free theories don’t tend to condense. Unless I am mistaken, for processes which appreciably involve the heavy quarks (above the QCD scale) the theory is asymptotically free/weakly coupled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hulsey essentially answered your question, qualitatively. Perhaps he should just post his comment as an answer. For quark masses larger than QCD's Λ~200MeV, weakly-coupled gluons cannot effect something as drastic as condensing the respective fermions. Chiral condensation is an intrinsically non-perturbative phenomenon.

For quark masses smaller than the scale of the quark condensate, ~250MeV, (our world's u, s, d:  2, 5, 95MeV), one may consider them as a perturbation around a χ-symmetric massless limit; that is, QCD may act to SSBreak the extant background χ-symmetry and condense, thus realizing it in the Goldstone-Nambu mode.

One may then perturb around this ideal chiral symmetry limit by m/(condensation-scale), and obtain realistic results. Lots of Lattice QCD simulation effort has gone into investigating the mechanism, and a proper answer should involve lattice reviews of these investigations. I  believe there have been lattice verifications of Dashen's formula (sometimes referred to as GMOR) breakdown, confirming that heavy-quark pseudoscalar-meson masses do *not* go as the square-root of the quark (>Λ) masses, as if they were underlain by chiral condensation.

So, if you did have a heavy quark condensate, how would you estimate it? How would you *dare* use it in Dashen’s formula? How would you know?

The qualitative argument  has been fleshed out by ultra technical Lattice simulations, I believe, without good review recommendations...
To assay *when* chiral perturbation theory breaks down, as discussed above, look at Edwards, Heller, & Narayanan (1998), "Spectral flow, condensate and topology in lattice QCD",  *Nucl Phys* **B535** (1-2) 403-422.

You might enjoy this: Jamin (2002), "Flavour-symmetry breaking of the quark condensate and chiral corrections to the Gell-Mann–Oakes–Renner relation", *Phys Lett* **B538** (1-2) 71-76.