# Fundamental scales in QCD

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics

How pion decay constant is linked to $\Lambda_{QCD}$? Are they the same thing unless multiplicative constants?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C040802/papers/L010.PDF, Eq 19-20

Comment: Nice reference, thank you!

Comment: That equation equates the two, for the sake of argument. They differ by a factor of less than 3...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same thing, although they are of the same order of magnitude, as is the chiral condensate. The pion decay constant quantifies the strength with which pseudoscalars couple to the chiral vacuum of QCD, in their role as Goldstone bosons: their amplitude to be pulled out of it by the SSBroken chiral current. $\Lambda_{QCD}$ is the characteristic energy scale of QCD, whose Compton wavelength is a typical hadronic radius, near the shell characteristic of chiral condensation.

The complete theoretical  connection resides in Dashen's formula for the masses of pseudogoldstone bosons, and is neatly summarized in section 5.5 of T. P. Cheng's & L. F. Li's tasteful book. If you were a glutton for detail, you might opt for S. Weinberg's (1996) *The Quantum Theory of Fields* (v2. Cambridge University Press.  ISBN 978-0-521-55002-4.  pp. 225–231). It is also often   referred to as Gell-Mann-Oakes-Renner (1968)  doi:10.1103/PhysRev.175.2195 in the sloppy shorthand of chiral perturbation theory.

It is a blending of a current algebra Ward identity with PCAC ($m_\pi^2 f_\pi^2=-\langle 0|[Q_5,[Q_5,H]]|0\rangle$),  so that the ***square*** of the mass of the pseudoglodstone boson is proportional to the explicit breaking part of the effective lagrangian, here linear in the quark masses.

For example, naively, the pion mass, which should have been zero for massless quarks as a full Goldstone boson of a perfect SSBroken chiral symmetry, now picks up a small value $m_\pi^2 \sim  m_q \Lambda^3/f_\pi^2$, where $m_q$ is the relevant light quark mass in the real world QCD Lagrangian, which *explicitly* breaks chiral symmetry; $f_\pi$ is the spontaneously broken chiral symmetry constant, about 90MeV; and Λ the fermion condensate value ~ 250MeV. The latter is taken routinely to be identical to $\Lambda_{QCD}$.

Crudely, for $f_\pi \sim 90$MeV and $m_\pi \sim 140$MeV,
$$
(90\cdot 140)^2 \sim 7\cdot (250)^3 
$$
is not that bad...